# Python OpenCV threading with tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a small python opencv code to predict age and gender. I also have a GUI tkinter library to print the age on a separate window.

```py
import cv2
import math
import time
import argparse
import requests
import tkinter as tk
import threading


window = tk.Tk()



def getFaceBox(net, frame,conf_threshold = 0.75):
    frameOpencvDnn = frame.copy()
    frameHeight = frameOpencvDnn.shape[0]
    frameWidth = frameOpencvDnn.shape[1]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frameOpencvDnn,1.0,(300,300),[104, 117, 123], True, False)

    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    bboxes = []

    for i in range(detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0,0,i,2]
        if confidence > conf_threshold:
            x1 = int(detections[0,0,i,3]* frameWidth)
            y1 = int(detections[0,0,i,4]* frameHeight)
            x2 = int(detections[0,0,i,5]* frameWidth)
            y2 = int(detections[0,0,i,6]* frameHeight)
            bboxes.append([x1,y1,x2,y2])
            cv2.rectangle(frameOpencvDnn,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),int(round(frameHeight/150)),8)
    
    
    

    return frameOpencvDnn , bboxes



faceProto = "opencv_face_detector.pbtxt"
faceModel = "opencv_face_detector_uint8.pb"

ageProto = "age_deploy.prototxt"
ageModel = "age_net.caffemodel"

genderProto = "gender_deploy.prototxt"
genderModel = "gender_net.caffemodel"

MODEL_MEAN_VALUES = (78.4263377603, 87.7689143744, 114.895847746)
ageList = ['(0-2)', '(4-6)', '(8-12)', '(15-20)', '(25-32)', '(38-43)', '(48-53)', '(60-100)']
genderList = ['Male', 'Female']


#load the network
ageNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(ageModel,ageProto)
genderNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(genderModel, genderProto)
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(faceModel, faceProto)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
padding = 20

while cv2.waitKey(1) < 0:
    #read frame
    t = time.time()
    hasFrame , frame = cap.read()

    if not hasFrame:
        cv2.waitKey()
        break
    #creating a smaller frame for better optimization
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame,(0,0),fx = 0.5,fy = 0.5)

    frameFace ,bboxes = getFaceBox(faceNet,small_frame)
    if not bboxes:
        print("No face Detected, Checking next frame")
        continue
    for bbox in bboxes:
        face = small_frame[max(0,bbox[1]-padding):min(bbox[3]+padding,frame.shape[0]-1),
                max(0,bbox[0]-padding):min(bbox[2]+padding, frame.shape[1]-1)]
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0, (227, 227), MODEL_MEAN_VALUES, swapRB=False)
        genderNet.setInput(blob)
        genderPreds = genderNet.forward()
        gender = genderList[genderPreds[0].argmax()]
        print("Gender : {}, conf = {:.3f}".format(gender, genderPreds[0].max()))

        ageNet.setInput(blob)
        agePreds = ageNet.forward()
        age = ageList[agePreds[0].argmax()]
        print("Age Output : {}".format(agePreds))
        print("Age : {}, conf = {:.3f}".format(age, agePreds[0].max()))

        label = "{},{}".format(gender, age)
        cv2.putText(frameFace, label, (bbox[0], bbox[1]-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow("Age Gender Demo", frameFace)
       
    print("time : {:.3f}".format(time.time() - t))

    window.mainloop()
```

The issue with this is that the opencv code will wait for the tkinter window to be closed before continuing processing. Thus the video from the webcam will hang until the window is closed.

How do I make this into a thread (or any other method) so that both windows executes normally without blocking?

Comment: X-Y problem. Don't mix two different GUI frameworks in the same program. If you need tk for something, use it to display the image as well.

Comment: since you're already aware of multithreading and you did ask how to use threads, why don't you show us your attempt at multithreading? hint: `import threading` is a good start, but you don't even use it

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77885289/how-can-i-send-data-from-my-application-to-a-website-via-port